# Swift - Launch the application without push notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am working with a project which requires when there is a notification from backend it will automatically launch the application from background or even after the device is restarted. However, from my knowledge, Apple doesn't allow us to do that. I made some researches and there is callkit. However, callkit is a little bit too much for me (because i don't need the VOIP). But, I need something quite similar (like whatsapp or hangouts )

The flow should be like:
Backend notification -> App will make a call like whatsapp/hangouts -> user accept -> application launches itself with a specific view ( not the call at all )

NOTE: I did try the push notification. However, the push notification requires users' action (actually tap the notification) and I need something else.

Anyone gives me advice please ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to make a general app could automatically launch, as you said Apple don't allow it.

Comment: I need to implement same scenario as yours in my ios app. Can you please guide me if you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, the Apple Push Notification service is the only service that can help you, if you do not want to use CallKit. To simulate a call like WhatsApp and Hangouts, you can use Apple's new Advanced Notifications for customized notification UI (available from iOS 10.0).

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/

> Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is the centerpiece of the remote notifications feature. It is a robust, secure, and highly efficient service for app developers to propagate information to iOS (and, indirectly, watchOS), tvOS, and macOS devices.
>
> Local notifications and remote notifications are ways to inform users when new data becomes available for your app, even when your app is not running in the foreground. For example, a messaging app might let the user know when a new message has arrived, and a calendar app might inform the user of an upcoming appointment.

More about Advanced Notifications:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/

Comment: i used the push notification. However, I am trying to do the same thing as Android. because in Android, developers can handle "services". For example, if the device is rebooted, the service will automatically start the application again. However, we cannot do that here :(

Comment: In iOS that is impossible. You can implement some app background processing mechanism. But that functionality will only be available when your app is already running.