# Open an app without any action over push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, alarm

I want to open an app over push notification without any user interaction.

The concept of my need is following.
User may receive push notification from server that time I want to open an app with some alarm tone.

> Normally, alarm is playing when app is in background but I need a way
>   to open as well without any user interaction on push alert.
>
> I have reviewed many Android apps has this feature. **Is there any luck to implement in iOS?**

We can easily open an application by tap on push alert but I want to open an app automatically over push alert.

**1. Do we need to create/add any extension to achieve this kind of thing?**

Please help me out.

Comment: They say it is impossible HERE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668629/swift-launch-the-application-without-push-notification

Comment: Even if there is a way, user will delete your app if it will interrupt their current activity. Why do you need this kind of behavior? Its not normal.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't even do anything to the notification data if the app was terminated let alone open the app automatically. I remember having Android apps that have this feature but alas (or maybe fortunately) it's not available on iOS

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible. I've never heard of such a "feature", and I'm honestly surprised Android allows this.

I don't ever want an app to open to the foreground without my permission (possibly stopping whatever I was doing).

**If it did, I would categorize it as a virus and a security breach.**

My instinct says that Apple feel the same way and would never allow such a thing.

Of course, apps open all the time in the background to execute code, but an app's coming into the foreground must be started by a user's explicit action.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

I am also surprised that Android allows this but it's done in Android. But I don't know how they guys has done also, I don't know it's official or not in Android.

Comment: Many modern banking apps are doing this for login/transaction verification. You go on their website, enter username/password and you receive a push notification on your phone that opens their app that asks for fingerprint verification. After you verify the fingerprint you are logged in on their site (or transaction completes). This is a very useful feature and not some virus/evil practice/whatever. If an app opens from a push notification without your concent/or for an invalid use case, just disable push notifications for that app or report them, as simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.App can't be opened without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

I cannot find such a way of doing it. So if you wanted to create your own extension or something running in the background I've some bad news for you: you can't. You could only run a listener for such a feature and as by definition you are in the background Apple would have to explicitly allow it.

Answer (score 1):

It's Not possible in iOS, to force launch an application. Once the notification comes from the server. The only way to launch app is tap on notification bar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. But we can launch the application from Mac terminal so if write the bash script when you get the notification then may be you can launch application.
The tool used are CFGUtil and Apple Configurator 2.

Answer (score 1):

#### No, you can't. It's **impossible** to open app **without** user interaction.

If you have any requirements like this, save the status & show the appropriate UI when the user opens the app.

*NB: IDK why the android still allows this. This is some NOT good stuff. Better you avoid that.*